# Rails + Paperclip + AWS: After watermark is added, new picture is not sent to Amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I added watermark processor for one size of image. But, all other versions of picture are uploaded to `S3`, except this one. I believe I had to notify `AWS` that I changed this size but I do not know how or where to do that...

Here is my code:

lib/paperclip_processors/watermark.rb

```
module Paperclip
class Watermark < Processor
attr_accessor :current_geometry, :target_geometry, :format, :whiny, :convert_options, :watermark_path, :overlay, :position

def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
   super
   geometry          = options[:geometry]
   @file             = file
   @crop             = geometry[-1,1] == '#'
   @target_geometry  = Geometry.parse geometry
   @current_geometry = Geometry.from_file @file
   @convert_options  = options[:convert_options]
   @whiny            = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
   @format           = options[:format]
   @format_output    = options[:format_output].nil? ? "jpg" : options[:format_output]
   @watermark_path   = options[:watermark_path]
   @position         = options[:position].nil? ? "SouthEast" : options[:position]
   @overlay          = options[:overlay].nil? ? true : false
   @current_format   = File.extname(@file.path)
   @basename         = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
 end

  def crop?
    @crop
  end

  def convert_options?
    not @convert_options.blank?
  end

  # Performs the conversion of the +file+ into a watermark. Returns the Tempfile
  # that contains the new image.
  def make
    dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
    dst.binmode

    if watermark_path
      command = "composite"

      params = %W[-gravity #{@position}]
      params += %W[-geometry '#{@watermark_offset}'] if @watermark_offset
      params += %W["#{watermark_path}" "#{fromfile}"]
      params += transformation_command
      params << "\"#{tofile(dst)}.#{@format_output}\""

    else
      command = "convert"
      params = [fromfile]
      params += transformation_command
      params << tofile(dst)
    end

    puts command
    puts "Params: " + params.to_s

    begin
      success = Paperclip.run(command, params.join(" "))
    rescue ArgumentError, Cocaine::CommandLineError
      raise Paperclip::Error, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
    end

    dst
  end

  def fromfile
    File.expand_path(@file.path)
  end

  def tofile(destination)
    File.expand_path(destination.path)
  end

  def transformation_command
    scale, crop = @current_geometry.transformation_to(@target_geometry, crop?)
    trans = %W[-resize "#{scale}"]
    trans += %W[-crop #{crop} +repage] if crop
    trans << convert_options if convert_options?
    trans
  end
end
end
```

and model:

```
require 'paperclip_processors/watermark'

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

                has_attached_file :picture, 
                :processors => [:watermark],
                styles: {
                  thumb: '100x100#',
                  small: '320x200#',
                  medium: '640x400#',
                  large: {
                          :geometry       => "920x575>",
                          :watermark_path => "#{Rails.root}/public/img/watermark.png"
                         }
                }
end
```

Comment: In console I can see that size is 0, and content type is "inode/x-empty"

[paperclip] saving /xxxxxx/pictures/000/000/027/large/capuccino1.jpg
[AWS S3 200 0.198011 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"xxxxxxx",:content_length=>0,:content_type=>"inode/x-empty",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: capuccino12013032
2-5616-q8fcjj20130322-5616-3rmuis,:key=>"xxxxx/pictures/000/000/027/large/capuccino1.jpg")